# EXCEL: Round Dot LineStyle for Cell Border

Tags: excel, vba, format, border, linestyle

Using VBA in excel for a Cell Border (not a chart):

Cannot set the `Borders.Linestyle` property to have the round dot linestyle (see attached photo). Using `.Linestyle = xlDot` results in the larger, square dashes rather than the smaller round dots.

I've also tried setting weight to `xlThin` but this does not seem to make a difference.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
.LineStyle = xlContinuous
.Weight = xlHairline
```

Comment: Welcome. Btw: I quickly fired the Macro-Recorder to find out. That's usually the best way to find these little things in Excel

Comment: I was doing that when first learning VBA but had totally forgot about that method of learning! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

With xlHairline you can attempt to use .Weight = xlHairline with .LineStyle = xlContinuous to get the thinnest line possible, which may look like a dotted line under certain conditions.

Sample code snippet:

```
With targetRange.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .Weight = xlHairline
    .Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)  ' Black
End With
```